# Unable to pass method to advice in byte buddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

Referencing:
[Problem migrating from AspectJ to Byte Buddy Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67504858/problem-migrating-from-aspectj-to-byte-buddy-plugin)

When I follow the example, but update it as it should be:

```
package plugin;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice;

public class TimingAdvice {
  @Advice.OnMethodEnter
  public static void onEnter(@Advice.Origin Method method)
      throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("method: " + method);
  }
}
```

I get:
Failed to transform class SomeAdvisedClass: [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map this reference for static method or constructor start: public SomeAdvisedClass()].

For whatever reason, it works as soon as I remove the Method argument from the advice to:

```
package plugin;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice;

public class TimingAdvice {
  @Advice.OnMethodEnter
  public static void onEnter(@Advice.Origin("#t") final String typeName,
  @Advice.Origin("#m") final String methodName)
      throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("type: " + typeName + ", method: " + methodName);
  }
}
```

I am on JDK21 with the latest version of byte buddy.

I want to pass the Method in because I want to inspect annotations on each parameter and as far as I know, I need the Method to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are intercepting static methods or constructors. In this case, `@Advice.This` cannot be assigned (in enter phase). You can define a property to rather bind `null`: `@Advice.This(nullIfEmpty = true)`.

Comment: Correction, I am not using the \@Advice.This - the issue is only when I use \@Advice.Origin Method method and try to use the method.  As soon as I remove '\@Advice.Origin Method method', it works.

Comment: Same goes for that. Use `Executable` as the type, so `Method` and `Constructor` can be assigned.